# Equivalent of subinacl.exe on linux / unix?

Tags: permissions, backup, acl

When modifying permissions on Windows I backup the ACLs to a file first using a commands like:

```
subinacl /noverbose /output=C:\temp\foldername_redir_permissions_backup_star_star.txt /subdirectories "W:\foldername\*.*"
```

and...

```
subinacl /noverbose /output=C:\temp\foldername_redir_permissions_backup.txt /subdirectories "W:\foldername\"
```

...to back them up.

And then if they need to be restored, a command like...

```
subinacl /playfile C:\temp\foldername_redir_permissions_backup_star_star.txt
```

...can be used to restore them.

---

So can the same thing be done for POSIX permissions on Linux / Unix?  And what about ACL extended permissions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setfacl` is designed to accept `getfacl` output as input. Meaning you can run `getfacl`, save the output to a file, do your thing, then restore the ACL. The exact procedure can vary depending on your platform. On Linux though:

```
  # Take a peek at the current ACL
[root@vlp-fuger ~]# getfacl newFile
# file: newFile
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
group:provisor:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r--

  # Backup ACL
[root@vlp-fuger ~]# getfacl newFile > newFile.acl

  # Remove the group permission, add another that we'll later want to get rid of
[root@vlp-fuger ~]# setfacl -x g:provisor newFile
[root@vlp-fuger ~]# setfacl -m g:ihtxadm:r-x newFile
[root@vlp-fuger ~]# getfacl newFile
# file: newFile
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
group:ihtxadm:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r--

  # Restore ACL to where it was
[root@vlp-fuger ~]# setfacl --restore=newFile.acl

  # Resulting ACL
[root@vlp-fuger ~]# getfacl newFile
# file: newFile
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
group:provisor:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

You can also use `--set-file` on the `setfacl` you use to restore and set it to `-` if you want to pipe the old ACL in. You can also use `getfacl -R` to backup the ACL's of entire directory trees.

Comment: WOW!  And that'll take the posix too?

Comment: Can you take the posix separately?  There aren't always ACLs...

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the standard owner/group permissions? If so then yeah, those are caught as part of backup process. I personally don't know of a way to save those short of modifying your backup file with whatever the file's current permissions are.

Comment: The only way I know to get those is to use etckeeper (it's a vcs of your choice with permissions)

Comment: The user/group are included in the backup, you'd only have to do something special if you didn't want to clobber changes you've made to those fields and only wanted to reset/restore just the ACL's